# Break array down into unique arrays for database insert

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [year] => 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997
    [make] => Ford
    [model] => Mustang, Mustang Cobra, Mustang GT
    [engine] => 302, 302 H/O, V6
)
```

I am wanting to insert unique rows into my database with all the possible solutions in the array.

For example:

```
id    year      make      model            engine
1     1994      Ford      Mustang          302
2     1994      Ford      Mustang Cobra    302
3     1994      Ford      Mustang GT       302
4     1994      Ford      Mustang          302 H/O
...and so on
```

I need to be able to break down that array to get all possible solutions into a unique row. Some columns may not have a value. For example, the array may only contain several Make's. I would like to insert all the unique possibilities into an array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1994, Ford, Mustang, 302
    [1] => and so on...
)
```

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: Look over to the right, under **Related**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple way, without database part, but I hope you can do that yourself:

```
$arr = array
(
    'year' => '1994, 1995, 1996, 1997',
    'make' => 'Ford',
    'model' =>'Mustang, Mustang Cobra, Mustang GT',
    'engine' => '302, 302 H/O, V6'
);

$years = explode(',',$arr['year']);
$makes = explode(',',$arr['make']);
$models = explode(',',$arr['model']);
$engines = explode(',',$arr['engine']);

foreach($years as $year) {
    foreach($makes as $make) {
        foreach($models as $model) {
            foreach($engines as $engine) {
               echo 'INSERT INTO yourtable '.$year.', '.$make.', '.$model.', '.$engine."\n";
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That's the way I had in mind doing it but I figured there was a better way than the foreach loops. I'll do it this way in a bit and if it works as I need it to I will check your answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you need "all unique possibilities" (combinations), the most direct approach is to iterate your information array nesting each item the other. And for each combination created from an iteration, create an array with the collected information and add to a final array. Eg:in kind of pseudo code

```
finalArray = new array()    
foreach(year as y) 
     foreach(make as m) 
          foreach(model as mo) 
               foreach(engine as e)
                    newArray = new array(y,m,mo,e)
                    add newArray to finalArray
```

hope it heps you